# Pass a list tp reducer output

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Can I pass List of values in reducer output ?

The code :-

public class XXX extends Reducer >

I need output as "List of Text" values .

Is it possible through Map Reduce ?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you need the output to look ?, should this be inside a file or a DB ?

Comment: REDUCER OUTPUT :- 0.1 {JACK,MALO,MARY}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following.

1. Create a custom List by extending the ArrayList or LinkedList.
2. Implement the Writable interface. You can leave the read method with dummy implementation and override the write the way you want the output to look like.
3. The reducer would have Custom List as the output value i.e. YourReducer

Comment: Hi Pradumnya!!!! My reducer Output will always be a LIST OF STRING . So I need to create a class (say Names) which implements Writable interface . I need to start my implementation from Point 2 of yours .Please help me , if I am in right track....Thanks

Comment: Update the question with code snippet for me to take a look at.

Comment: I have made the Custom Writable Code . How can I pass the same code to you for analyzing ? Please do let me know .

Answer (score 0):

I think your mapper should look like this

```
Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,ArrayWritable>
```

Reducer should look like this

```
Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,ArrayWritable>
```

In both signatures pay attention to ArrayWriteable.

There are six Writable collection types Array
Writable, ArrayPrimitiveWritable, TwoDArrayWritable, MapWritable,
SortedMapWritable, and EnumSetWritable.

The default TextOutputFormat invoked toString() on both key and value ArrayWritable overrides its toString() method, so you should get something close to what you have mentioned out of the box just by using this collection.